# MySQL Large Insert Update Query

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL 8 RDS (innodb) instance that I am trying to insert / update to.

The target table contains approx 120m rows and I am trying to insert 2.5m to the table from a csv. Some of the data in the source table may already exist in the target table which is constrained by a primary key, in which case update.

Having done some research I have found that the quickest way seems to be to do a bulk load from the source table into a temporary table, then a

```
insert into target_table 
select col1, col2 from source table a
on duplicate key update col1 = a.col1, col2 = a.col2
```

However this seems to be taking hours.

Is there a best practice to optimise inserts of this sort?

Would it be quicker to separate the inserts into inserts an updates separately? Can I disable indexes in the target table (I know this is possible for myisam)?

Thanks

Comment: Any reason you're not using [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlimport.html)?

Comment: because I am on Amazon RDS and can't run shell commands

Comment: You can use the [bulk insert method](https://medium.com/@benmorel/high-speed-inserts-with-mysql-9d3dcd76f723)

Comment: "can't run shell commands" -- not even on your own machine? `mysqlimport` can connect remotely, you know.

Comment: Is one of the columns `col1` or `col2` the primary key of the target table?

Comment: Also, make sure you index the corresponding column in the source table.

Comment: Fastest way would be to use transactions and force MySQL to commit every 1000 (or even 10 000 rows since it's RDS). Since you're importing a CSV, do you have a script of some sort that parses it first and then queries the db with inserts? Using bulk inserts is actually slow (`INSERT INTO X (column_list) VALUES (values1), (values2)` for several reasons: 1) you can produce really long queries that have to be parsed and 2) you can exceed MySQL's `max_packet_size` value. It should be avoided if possible.